# In the "Select Media" dialog, where are the search facets defined at in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client, content-search, content-editor

This is for `Sitecore 8.1 Update 3`.

In the `Select Media` dialog that pops up on certain media fields (for example, clicking `Browse` on an image field), I want to know where the search facets are defined at. Are they defined within the CMS or in a configuration file? Can you modify the behavior of these facets or create your own?

The search facets I'm specifically interested in are highlighted in the screenshot below:

- All image files
- All video files
- My images
- Recently uploaded images
- Recently uploaded videos
- Recently uploaded by me

[image: Select Media Dialog, with highlighted search facets]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've researched this a bit myself and come up with the following answer. If there's a better, more general way of answering this for every dialog, or if anyone has more specific information about how everything is set up please don't hesitate to answer!

As of Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 (I'm not sure how many versions this is applicable for), a certain set of dialoges are defined in the core database under the following location: `/sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs` (Item ID: `{648AFADA-20C7-413A-9636-44703A16DFCF}`). Highlighted in the image below is the dialog that I'm specifically asking about: `SelectMediaDialog` (Item ID: `{ACA0FE9D-0FFD-4043-96DC-B702D1B44F39}`).

[image: SelectMediaDialog node in the core database]

Under every node that has a template of `Speak-DialogPage`, there's a `SearchConfigs` folder that resides under each `Speak-DialogPage`'s `PageSettings` node.

[image: SearchConfigs node]

The `SearchConfigs` folder contains a set of items that are used to define which search facets are available. The fields on these items are "predefined" and have explicit hardcoded meaning. For example the `RecentlyUploadedByMe` item which defines the `Recently uploaded by me` facet seen in the first screenshot has the following fields set:

1. The `Base Templates` field defines which templates to search on, and is currently set with all known media types:

[image: Base Templates field set on the SearchPanel Config item]

2. Certain filters that limit the search to items created by the current user and items created within the last seven days.

[image: Date and User filters on the SearchPanel Config item]

The latter set of "Date" and "User" fields appear to be used by the `Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Search.SetSearchParameters` (in "Sitecore.Speak.ItemWebApi.dll") processor. This processor will check for that particular set fields and then modify the search query in the appropriate fashion. So if you wanted to extend the or modify the available behavior, you'd have to extend the `SearchPanel Config` template, create your own processor and then patch it in. Here's the currently decompiled code for the `Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Search.SetSearchParameters` processor, so you can see it in action:

```cs
public override void Process(SearchArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  Item searchDescriptor = args.SearchDescriptor;
  if (searchDescriptor == null)
    return;
  this.SetTemplateFilter(args);
  if (searchDescriptor["UpdatedWithin7Days"] == "1")
  {
    DateTime to = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1.0);
    DateTime from = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7.0);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => MethodExtensions.Between<DateTime>(i.Updated, from, to, Inclusion.Both)));
  }
  if (searchDescriptor["CreatedWithin7Days"] == "1")
  {
    DateTime to = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1.0);
    DateTime from = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7.0);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => MethodExtensions.Between<DateTime>(i.CreatedDate, from, to, Inclusion.Both)));
  }
  if (searchDescriptor["UpdatedByCurrentUser"] == "1")
  {
    string userName = Context.GetUserName().Replace("\\", string.Empty);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => i["parsedcreatedby"] == userName));
  }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDescriptor["UpdatedBySpecificUser"]))
  {
    string userName = searchDescriptor["UpdatedBySpecificUser"].Replace("\\", string.Empty);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => i["parsedcreatedby"] == userName));
  }
  if (searchDescriptor["CreatedByCurrentUser"] == "1")
  {
    string userName = Context.GetUserName().Replace("\\", string.Empty);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => i["parsedcreatedby"] == userName));
  }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchDescriptor["CreatedBySpecificUser"]))
  {
    string userName = searchDescriptor["CreatedBySpecificUser"].Replace("\\", string.Empty);
    args.Queryable = Queryable.Where<ConvertedSearchResultItem>(args.Queryable, (Expression<Func<ConvertedSearchResultItem, bool>>) (i => i["parsedcreatedby"] == userName));
  }
  string queryString1 = WebUtil.GetQueryString("pageSize", searchDescriptor["PageSize"]);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString1))
    args.PageSize = MainUtil.GetInt(queryString1, 0);
  string queryString2 = WebUtil.GetQueryString("pageIndex");
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString2))
    return;
  args.PageIndex = MainUtil.GetInt(queryString2, 0);
}
```